# Exercise 6.2.21 Introduction to Real Analysis by Jiri Lebl

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Let $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+(nx)^2}$. Notice that $f_n$ are differentiable functions.
>
> a) Show that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$

$\lim\sup|\frac{x}{1+(nx)^2}| =\lim |\frac1{2n}| = 0$

> b) Show that $|f'_n(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$ and all $n$.

$|f'_n(x)| = |\frac1{1+(nx)^2}||1-\frac{2(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^2}| =  |\frac1{1+(nx)^2}||\frac{1-(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^2}|< \frac{(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^2} \le 1$.

> c) Show that $\{f'_n\}$ converges ponitwise to a function discontinuous at the origin.

Given $x$, if $n$ goes to infinity, doesn't $f'_n(x)$ converges to $0$?

> d) Let $\{a_n\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers. Define
> $$g_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{-k}f_n (x-a_k).$$
> Show that $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Shouldn't $f_n$ be replaced by $f_k$? In that case, $\lim \sup |2^{-1}||f_k(x-a_k)|^{1/k} = 0$ since $f_k$ uniformly converge to $0$. So $g_n$ uniformly converges. But, how do we know that it converges to $0$?

> e) Show that $\{g'_n\}$ converges pointwise to a function $\phi$ that is discontinuous at every rational number and continuous at every irrational number. In particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty} g'_n(x) \not= 0$ for every rational number $x$.

I have no idea.

I have some difficulty in solving the last three questions. I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: For (b): $$|\frac1{1+(nx)^2}||\frac{1-(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^2}|< \frac{(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^2}$$ is false when $x=0,$ so you need to revisit that one.  And on a related note: For (c): What is $f'_n(0)$?  Does it converge to $0$?  .... As for parts (d) and (e), it might help to investigate what $g_n'(x)$ is for the $g_n$ defined in the problem, and also your proposed correction.  I believe you might find your proposal doesn't satisfy the results of (e).

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, $f_n(x)\to 0$ pointwise. Note that the $f_n$ are differentiable and defined on all of $\mathbb R$. Therefore any maximum must be attained at a point $x_n$ such that $f_n'(x_n)=0$. So we compute 
$$
f_n'(x) = \frac{1-n^2 x^2}{\left(1+n^2 x^2\right)^2},
$$
and note that $$f_n'(x)=0\iff 1-n^2x^2=0\iff x = \frac1n.$$
It follows that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n\left(\frac1n\right) = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n(1+1^2)} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac1n = 0, $$
and hence $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero.

It is clear that $(1+n^2x^2)\geqslant1$ and $1-n^2x^2\leqslant 1$ and therefore
$$
f_n'(x) = \frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}\leqslant 1.
$$
For $x\ne 0$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-n^2x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2} = 0,$$
but for $x=0$, $f_n'(0) = 1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(0)=1$. It follows that the limit of $f_n'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

For d) and e) I am not sure.